Google Chat Bot Doesn’t Respond in Thread for First Message but Works for Subsequent Messages
I’m building a Google Chat bot that should respond in the same thread where it is mentioned.
I use google chat api and pass data to google cloud function via webhook. Unfortunately the response doesn't always go to the right thread.
However, the bot behaves differently depending on the context:
First Message in a Thread: If the bot is tagged in the first message of a thread, it responds as a new message in the space, not within the thread.
Subsequent Messages in the Thread: If the bot is tagged in the second or later messages of the same thread, it replies correctly within that thread.
Current Implementation: Here’s the response structure I’m returning in my bot code:
{
  "text": assistant_response,
  "thread": {
    "name": google_thread_name
  }
}

The google_thread_name value is directly taken from the event data, and it has the correct format: spaces/{space_id}/threads/{thread_id}
Despite this, the bot does not respond in the thread for the first message. Any insights on what might be going wrong or how to fix this behavior? Thank you!
I did a test and the first message in a thread differs from the next ones by one field:

First Message in a Thread:
The payload does not include the threadReply field.
context.
Next Message in a Thread:
The payload includes "threadReply": true.

I tried responding to the bot in a different way, but a more complicated response results in an error in Google Chat.
